Can a ViewModel have @Composable functions?
I have a ViewModel class defined as below:
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _count = MutableStateFlow(0)

    val count = _count.asStateFlow()

    fun increaseCount() {
        _count.update {
            it + 1
        }
    }
}

and I define a @Composable function as below:
@Composable
fun MainActivityViewModel.MainScreen() {
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    ) {
        Text(text = "${count.collectAsState().value}")
        Button(onClick = ::increaseCount) {
            Text(text = "Increase")
        }
    }
}

then I use the MainScreen function in my MainActivity:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            DemoTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val viewModel = viewModel<MainActivityViewModel>()
                    viewModel.MainScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I can think of two pros:

no need to inject ViewModel in MainScreen
objects inside MainScreen(and its children) can have a lifecycle scoped to the ViewModel

My question is:

is there any cons defining @Composable functions this way?
can I tie a koin scope to this ViewModel?

I run the above code，and it seems okay. I'm new to koin, and I havn't tried koin yet.

it's not an good approach to define your ui in your viewModel , view model will live until your app gets destroyed , use view model to communicate between your activity and logic.

In MVVM, the viewModel is tied to a view and is responsible to handle any logic related to it. Why would you want views to be inside of your viewModel? That completely breaks the MVVM paradigm.

Using kotlin's extension function grammar, the ui is not in ViewModel. @Composable functions are not objects, nor classes. They are functions, but should be treated as classes. So the code can be interpreted as ViewModel supporting View. I'm not using MVVM here. The relationship between MVVM and ViewModel is like recipe and pot. In the kitchen of Android,   ViewModel is the perfect pot to cook the MVVM recipe, but still can be used for other purpose. Here the purpose of ViewModel is to create a limited scope for objects(not just ui state, repositories can be scoped, and etc).

For example I want to run 3rd party SDKm by using rememberLauncherForActivityResult which is @Composable, but I don't want to put all logic to the compose directly. I want to normally notify ViewModel when the user presses the button and then ViewModel should call SDK, store the result to the DB, and send a flow update to UI to reflect that. I don't consider rememberLauncherForActivityResult as UI thing.

The very first reason that we should separate views from viewModel, especially in Compose, is that viewModel's lifecycle is longer than your screen. It will survive through recompositions. However, this way you are entangling recompositions with your viewModel, which is very wrong.
